# Futur im temporalen Nebensatz nach "wenn"?

Tags: tense

In meiner Muttersprache wird im Temporalsatz nach der Konjunktion *wenn* nie das Futur gesetzt. Ich habe mich heute bei dem Gedanken ertappt, dass ich nie darauf geachtet habe, wie es im Deutschen damit aussieht. Kann im Deutschen bei der Beschreibung einer zukünftigen Handlung nach der Konjunktion *wenn* das Futur verwendet werden?

Etwa so?

> Wenn ich Zeit **haben werde**, helfe ich dir.

(klingt seltsam für mein Ohr)

Oder

> Wenn/sobald ich Zeit **habe**, helfe ich dir.

(Die Konjunktion *wenn* (bei Zukunftsbezogenheit) wird beim Übertragen aus meiner Muttersprache ins Deutsche durch *sobald* übersetzt, deshalb füge ich hier *sobald* hinzu.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sobald) heißt *sobald* soviel wie *in dem Augenblick, da …; gleich wenn*.

> Sobald ich Zeit habe ...

beschreibt also den Augenblick, in dem feststeht, dass ich mich *sofort* ... widmen kann.

> Ich werde Zeit haben.

ist eine Aussage über die Zukunft. Wenn ich also nun sage:

> Sobald ich Zeit haben werde ...

dann bezeichnet *sobald* den Augenblick, in dem feststeht, dass ich in der auf diesen Augenblick folgenden Zukunft Zeit haben werde.

Abgesehen davon, dass solche Prognosen unmöglich sind, weil die Zukunft eben nie feststeht, dürfte das nur in den seltensten Fällen gemeint sein.

Futur 1 ist immer mit einer gewissen Unsicherheit verbunden. *Sobald* drückt aber gerade aus, dass zu diesem Zeitpunkt Sicherheit besteht.

Deshalb sagt man:

> Sobald ich Zeit habe, helfe ich dir.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Betrifft die Erklärung auch die Konjunktion "wenn"? z.B. in meiner Muttersprache kann man nicht sagen "Wenn ich zu Hause sein werde, rufe ich dich an." Ich habe "sein werde" ("Wenn ich nächste Woche in Berlin sein werde, schicke ich dir eine Postkarte." (?) in so einem Satz nie gehört und habe mich gefragt, ob es tatsächlich eine feste Regel im Deutschen gibt → kein Futur nach "wenn"?

Comment: Ja. Und auch wenn *wenn* im Sinne von *falls* benutzt wird. Ob man das als feste Regel bezeichnen kann, weiß ich nicht. Es ist ja eher eine Frage der Semantik.